# Jquery .html to .val

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this in a form:

```
<span name="totalprice" id="totalprice">0</span>
```

and this  jquery code:

```
$('#totalprice').html((data * $('#numlic2').val() - (data * $('#numlic2').val() * $('#persent').val() / 100)).toFixed(2));
```

i recive data from php and replace it in the span field replacing the 0. I want to post the value of the totalprice but when i post it its blank so i think i have to assign the .html to .val am i wrong?

how can i do that in jquery?

Comment: `$('#totalprice').text()` will set the text of the span

Comment: value of `data` and other input fields

Comment: So i just replace with this: $('#totalprice').text((data * $('#numlic2').val() - (data * $('#numlic2').val() * $('#persent').val() / 100)).toFixed(2)); ?

Answer (score 0):

You place 0 as default or initial value in `span` and you said you are getting blank in `span` then it mean something went wrong with you PHP code. Your PHP returns nothing.

jQuery `html()` is ok to replace the inner HTML of an element. You can use `text()` to change the text value of an element.